# Notation, abbreviation $a.s.$ measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, notation

Could you tell me what $m - a. s.$ means in measure theory? Here $m$ is a measure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost surely sounds like probability theory. And it means the probability is $1$.

Comment: Thank you! Probability is a measure, so I didn't think it would make a difference. Thank you again for answering.

Comment: @Stanley In general measures you say "almost everywhere" instead. But it's really the same thing.