# What does a.s.P. mean in this context?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, terminology, independence

I am reading a statistics book, "Sufficient Dimension Reduction" by Bing Li. In Chapter 2, it says:

> We say that $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ are conditional independent given $\mathcal{G}_3$, ...,if for every $A \in \mathcal{G}_1$ and  $B \in \mathcal{G}_2$, we have $P(A \cap B | \mathcal{G}_3)=P(A|\mathcal{G}_3) P(B | \mathcal{G}_3), a.s.P.$

What does a.s.P. mean in this context? I didn't find clues in previous texts, so I guess this should be a pretty common symbol.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731283

Comment: A property $\mathcal{P}$ holds $P$-a.s. if the set $B:=\{x:\mathcal{P}(x)=false\}$ has $P$ measure $0$, that is $P[A]=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two measurable functions $f,g$ are said to be equal $\mu$-almost everywhere (shorthand: $\mu$-a.e.) if $\mu (\{x \, : \, f(x) \neq g(x)\}) = 0$. In probability theory, the more common terminology is "almost surely" (a.s.) instead of almost everywhere. If one wants to specify the probability measure, one can say "almost surely for $P$" (a.s.$P$.).

In your case, notice that $P(A \cap B | \mathcal{G}_3)$, $P(A|\mathcal{G}_3)$, and $P(B|\mathcal{G}_3)$ are each random variables (i.e. measurable functions on a probability space), hence the statement means that for the set:

$$T = \{ \omega \in \Omega \, : \, P(A \cap B | \mathcal{G}_3)(\omega) \neq  P(A|\mathcal{G}_3)(\omega) P(B|\mathcal{G}_3)(\omega)\}$$ we have $P(T) = 0$.